# Rails Associations - Do I need has many and also belongs to together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a class Category and a class Post, post belongs to a category then I make a `t.belongs_to` in Post migration, but do I have to necessarily declare a `t.has_many` in Category? If not, if I have to use just one, which is the best to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `belongs_to` and `has_many` will just create an association method.

For example, use this:

```
class User
    has_many :cars
end
```

if you want to be able to access cars from current user. Such as: `current_user.cars`.

Or use this:

```
class Car
    belongs_to :user
end
```

if you want to be able to access user from the instance of car. For example: `Car.lost_and_found.user`.

In most cases, you will usually need both ways, so then use both.

Answer (score -1):

No you don't need to. `t.has_many` is not available on migrations and also more importantly, doesn't do anything for the table. However, `belongs_to` actually translates to a foreign key in the table linking the relationship.

For all methods that exist for a `create_table` e.g. creating references which also an alias for `belongs_to` refer to this documentation:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table#227-All-methods

Comment: @VitorFalcão Your question was about migrations. You don't use has_many in a migration -- there is no method for has_many in a migration file.